# Add 3 months to the Opportunity start Date field

Tags: validation-rule

I have a field membership start date and the validation rule need to fire when the membership start date is 3 months later than today it has to throw error.

Data type of membership start date is "Date" and API name is "npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c".

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give more details.

If you just need validation rule to check if the npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c is not later than three months from now just use this in the validation rule

npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c > ADDMONTHS(TODAY(), 3)

Or if you meant something that is triggered after three months see below!!!

I think your concept is not quite right for that case. I think instead of validation rule you must use Scheduled flow that runs daily and has a formula inside that is checking if today()=AddMonths(npe01__Membership_Start_Date__c,3) (not exact formula names, but you will get the idea I think). And if this formula evaluates to TRUE then send mail.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_resources_formula.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_considerations_design_formulas.htm&type=5

Please share if this answers your question or you need more details.

Comment: You can also use Scheduled process action see details here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=5 But I do not recommend that, because that way you would have processes "hanging" for three months in the system and many more things to break.